# Routing not working properly on cake

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, router

I migrated a cake website from one server to another, but in statics pages is showing a blank page, this is happening in two case scenarios right now

Scenario1:

```
$this->redirect(Router::url(array('controller' => 'staticpages', 
                            'action' => 'message', 'messageSlug' => 'welcome')));
```

Scenario2:

```
$link = Router::url(array('controller' => 'staticpages',
              'action' => 'message', 'messageSlug' => 'thanks-for-registering'));
```

Comment: Any error messages if you set debug level to 1, or anything in the error logs?

Comment: I'm really new with cake, and don't know how to set debug level to 1 :(

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook PHP SDK is interfering. It's probably throwing an error before Cake can properly redirect (the headers are already sent by `groofi__extra_facebook.php`.

Have a look what's happening in `groofi__extra_facebook.php` where the error seems to be stemming from. Probably your new server configuration is missing a vital component, is `cURL` present, for example?

Comment: it wasn't there, but it was because this didn't working:     if(!session_id()) session_start();